# Is the level of carbon monoxide on Mars at an expected equilibrium level?

Tags: mars, planetary-atmosphere, astrochemistry

Is the level of carbon monoxide in the atmosphere of Mars (0.0747%) exactly what would be expected under equilibrium conditions given the ambient Martian atmospheric temperature, pressure and composition? And in line with the low levels of oxygen (0.174%) present?